# XGBoost non-linear regression

Tags: regression, xgboost, logarithmic

Is it possible to use XGBoost regressor to do non-linear regressions?

I know of the objectives `linear` and `logistic`.
The `linear` objective works very good with the `gblinear` booster.
This made me wonder if it is possible to use XGBoost for non-linear regressions like logarithmic or polynomial regression.

a) Is it generally possible to make polynomial regression like in CNN where XGBoost approximates the data by generating n-polynomial function?
b) If a) is generally not possible, would it be possible to declare a curve with its parameters and let XGBoost figure out the values of the parameters? (To give an example) Assume we guess that the curve can be approximated with:

$$
10^{a\log_{k}({x})-b}
$$

XGBoost would have to figure out $a$, $k$, and $b$. $x$ would be a given feature.

Comment: As a heads up, polynomial regression is a type of linear regression. You might want to watch [this](https://youtube.com/watch?v=rVviNyIR-fI) video by MathematicalMonk (Jeff Miller).

Answer (score 3):

[Boosting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2752.pdf) is just a special way to fit some model by trying to successively/repeatedly "explain" the residual. See a minimal example for a [linear booster here](https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/l2_boosting.R). So essentially the `xgboost` model with `gblinear` will be a ["normal" linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521549/what-exactly-is-the-gblinear-booster-in-xgboost).

From your question I would not expect that a linear booster delivers good results against the backdrop of your problem. I think if you want to use other models than NN, you have several options.

- Use boosting with "tree based" (`gbtree`). This will fit a model which is essentially "non-parametric". However, the success of this strategy will depend on the explanatory power of your "x" variables (which you did not mention in the question).
- Use linear-style models with more general structure ([i.e. generalised additiove models, GAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model)). These model family is extremely well suited to fit highly non-linear functions. Find a [minimal example here](https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/GAM_regression_splines_simulated_data.R). There are GAM for Python and R. My minimal example would yield the following result (see figure). The blue line is a "normal" linear model, the black line is a fitted GAM model (red is the ground truth).
- If you know the parameterization of your model (more or less), you could also define a linear model (with proper parameterization) to solve your model. However, this seems to be a less attractive solution. It can be daunting to find a proper representation for the data.

[Introduction to Statistical Learning (ISL)](https://www.statlearning.com/) provides a good overview of GAM models if you want to have a further look. There are also [Python examples](https://github.com/JWarmenhoven/ISLR-python).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peter. I asked because we got an assignment in University. Everybody got an ML task. I got XGBoost where I used it successfully for classification. I've talked with a college that has LSTM for a Timeseries problem. Then I saw that XGBoost can do regression and gave it a shot with simple functions (`kx+d` style). After some success with those, I tried to get into more complicated ones and hit a wall. So that was my motivation for this question. I'll upload a notebook somewhere to make my question more detailed. Your answer is still highly appreciated.